# How to delete an image using Notification pending intent action?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I built the notification with actions and one of the action is `Delete`.

I have a screenshot and his path... When user click on `Delete` button in notification image should be deleted.

Question is: how to configure `PendingIntent` that user can click on `Delete` button and remove the image by path...?

**EDIT**

I thought about some `Foreground service` implementation of `WorkManager` implementation, but I am not sure that it is the right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JakeB I am a little bit improved his answer and this is what I got

```
public class DeleteImageService extends IntentService
{
    private final static String TAG = DeleteImageService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int DELETE_IMAGE_SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    public static final String EXTRA_SCREENSHOT_PATH = "extra_screenshot_path";
    public static final String DELETE_IMAGE_SERVICE = "delete_image_service";

    public DeleteImageService()
    {
        super(DELETE_IMAGE_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, DeleteImageService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_DELETE.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_SCREENSHOT_PATH))
        {
            String path = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SCREENSHOT_PATH);
            FileManager.deleteFileBy(path);
            Logger.log(Log.ERROR, TAG, path);
            PushNotificationManager.getInstance(this).getScreenshotNotificator(this).closeNotification();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    public static PendingIntent pendingIntent(@NonNull final Context context,//
                                              @NonNull final String iPath)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeleteImageService.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SCREENSHOT_PATH, iPath);
        PendingIntent pIntent;
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, DELETE_IMAGE_SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pIntent;
    }
}
```

This code support android version <26 and also don't request permission for foreground service.

Answer (score 1):

Foreground Service would work well in this instance, sample below:

```
public class DeleteImageService extends IntentService {

    public DeleteImageService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_PATH)) {
                string path = intent.getString(EXTRA_PATH);
                // Delete image in path
            }
        }
    }

    static PendingIntent pendingIntent(Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeleteImageService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PATH, path);
        return PendingIntent.getForegroundService(context, 1, retrieve, 0);
    }
}
```